# To find the daily return of stock price greater than 2%

Tags: python

To find the daily return of stock price greater than 2%, I have the Close date column, which I use to compute the percentage change for each day. Now to compute the probability of getting a daily return of greater than 2%.

I used the below code:

```
glaxo_df['gain'] = glaxo_df.Close.pct_change()  #To find the percentage change on each day
(glaxo_df["gain"]>0.02).value_counts(dropna=True)#To compute the probability,The true-86, total-1739, so the probability is 0.049
```

But here is another method that fetches a different result:

```
print('Mean:', round(glaxo_df.gain.mean(), 4))
print('Standard Deviation: ', round(glaxo_df.gain.std(), 4))
stats.norm.cdf(0.02,
glaxo_df.gain.mean(),
glaxo_df.gain.std())   #Gives a probability of 0.071
```

Apparently the first code isnt right, can anyone explain why it isnt?

Comment: Hi Shraddha S, welcome to Stack Overflow. Take the [tour] if you haven't yet! I reformatted your question a bit to make the code clearer, and I updated the tags a bit. You may want to add additional tags for the libraries you're using, since experts in those libraries may be more likely to be able to help you with your problem. It might also help if you elaborate a bit on how you know the second code is more correct than the first code.

Comment: How do you know the daily return data follows normal distribution??? Did you verify it by normal test?

Comment: Hi Shayan,
It is close to normal distribution, I just plotted a histogram to verify it. So is the difference because the second code computes based on normal distribution?